# Reading and Parsing a .MID file with Lua?

Tags: parsing, file-io, lua, midi

I am trying to read a .MID file with Lua and then parsing it into a table with all of the notes (ie {"A", "B#", "Cb", etc.}) but I cannot manage to read the file correctly. I use io.open and file:lines() but writing those same lines into another midi file results in a non-working midi file.

Is there any easier way to read and parse a .MID file with Lua?

Answer (score 4):

The [Standard MIDI File](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIDI#File_formats) format is binary, not text.  So you cannot expect to read it as "lines" at all.  Instead, you'll need to use the `read` function to get bytes and inspect them.  You might be better off finding a C library for MIDI files and binding it to Lua.

Comment: but what about the "b" argument in io.open for reading binary files?

Comment: Sure, it may be a good idea to use that, but it does not mean you can read "lines" out then.  You still need to treat the file as binary, and fundamentally the "lines" function is looking for newline characters, which mean something other than "new line" in MIDI.

Answer (score 4):

.MID files (presumably Standard MIDI format) are binary, not text. Reading them with `file:lines()` will not work. You need to read the entire thing into a "string" (Lua strings can hold arbitrary bytes of data) with `file:read("*a")` instead; this will read the entire file into a single string. You also need to make sure that you open the file in binary mode (for platforms where this makes a difference).

Answer (score 4):

There seems to be a framework called [MIDI.lua](http://www.pjb.com.au/comp/lua/MIDI.html) for parsing MIDI data. Not sure how well it handles MIDI files, though.